# Choosing proper edit session for Enterprise Geodatabases using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase, editing

There are 2 databases A and B; Each one has two tables: Table1 and Table2, both were created with the same script, defining for both: fields, versioning and archiving.

It is required to delete some rows in both tables and, of course in both databases.

A script was prepared:

```
def remove_items(from_table, ids):
    log.add("Start to clean orphan objects from: {0}".format(from_table))
    total_to_delete = 0
    fields = arcpy.ListFields("{0}.{1}".format(user_do, from_table))
    if "INSPECTION_ID" in [f.baseName for f in fields]:
        with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("{0}.{1}".format(user_do, from_table), ["INSPECTION_ID"]) as count_cursor:
            for row in count_cursor:
                if row[0] not in ids:
                    total_to_delete += 1

        row_counter = 0
        with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("{0}.{1}".format(user_do, from_table), ["INSPECTION_ID"]) as table_cursor:
            for row in table_cursor:
                if row[0] not in ids:
                    table_cursor.deleteRow()
                    row_counter += 1
                    log.add("In table {0} deleted rows {1} / {2}".format(from_table, row_counter, total_to_delete))

            log.add("Total rows deleted from {0} : {1}".format(from_table, row_counter))


with arcpy.da.Editor(arcpy.env.workspace) as edit:
    log.add("This script may take a while to finish.")
    remove_items("Table1", orphan_ids)
    remove_items("Table2", orphan_ids)
```

The script is run against Database A, and it runs without any issue.
The script is run against Database B, and it generates the following error:

```
['RuntimeError: Insufficient permissions [Database_B.Table_2][STATE_ID = 2880]\n', '\nThe above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:\n\n', 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n', '  File "C:/T/Repos/RemoveOrphanInspections.py", line 136, in <module>\n    main(argv[1:])\n', '  File "C:/T/Repos/RemoveOrphanInspections.py",'SystemError: <built-in method __exit__ of Workspace Editor object at 0x0000019EDF973180> returned a result with an error set\n']
```

Permissions were checked, and the data owner user (the one used to run the script), has the permissions of Select, Insert, Update and Delete.

I make a change to the script:

```
with arcpy.da.Editor(arcpy.env.workspace) as edit:
    log.add("This script may take a while to finish.")
    remove_items("Table1", orphan_ids)

edit = arcpy.da.Editor(arcpy.env.workspace)
edit.startEditing(False, True)
edit.startOperation()
remove_items("Table2", orphan_ids)
edit.stopOperation()
edit.stopEditing(True)
```

Now the script runs with out issue.

With this modification I am using two edit sessions, therefore there is two transaction scopes (That was not the original plan).

Versioning, archiving, permissions and fields are the same in both Databases.

How could I check the differences between the Database_A.Table2 and Database_B.Table2?

Which property of the table should be checked to choose a proper Edit session management?